# Renamed Desktop folder and all files disapeared

Tags: folders, desktop, macos

I was using the program Lightroom and I tried to rename the Desktop folder to DESKTOP but when I clicked enter, it said "This folder can not be changed." I clicked "ok" and then all the files in my Desktop were gone.

Where did all these files go? Are they gone?

Comment: open terminal and see if you can see the folderDesktop in your home directory, then go into that folder and see if the files are there.

Comment: The folder Desktop is there, but nothing is in it

Comment: Did you have files on your desktop/screen before the rename?

Comment: Yes, I had a bunch of files and folders.